# Building application with ros using cmake placed outside the project dir

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ros

I have a cmake file, which I use to build application without ament. I need to pass various options and macro definition to this cmake. This cmake is common to many project and placed at a common directory.

I want to build some project with ros, I found ament but how to pass that common cmake file to ament. What i know ament search cmake in src directory, which I don't want.

Or any other way to build ros with this common cmake which is not in project directory?